# Symfony form collection

Tags: php, forms, entity-framework, symfony

In Symfony I have two entities: Question and Answer. They have a relation of one to many, where one question can have many answers. Using thees entities I am trying to build a form with text fields where the user can edit data from thees entities. Reading the Symfony cookbook documentation I understand that I need to use a collection of forms to display the multiple answers for a question. For what I understand the question form will generate the question data, and this will also embed the Answer form that will have all the answers. At this point I am stuck with this error:

> Could not load type "QuizBundle\Entity\Answer

Can someone help me solve this and build the form with the question and the answers? Thanks

Here is my Answer Entity:

```
/**
 * Answer
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="answer")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="QuizBundle\Repository\AnswerRepository")
 */
class Answer
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Question", inversedBy="answers")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="question_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $question;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="answer", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $answer;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="isCorrect", type="boolean")
     */
    private $isCorrect;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set answer
     *
     * @param string $answer
     *
     * @return Answer
     */
    public function setAnswer($answer)
    {
        $this->answer = $answer;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get answer
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAnswer()
    {
        return $this->answer;
    }

    /**
     * Set isCorrect
     *
     * @param boolean $isCorrect
     *
     * @return Answer
     */
    public function setIsCorrect($isCorrect)
    {
        $this->isCorrect = $isCorrect;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isCorrect
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getIsCorrect()
    {
        return $this->isCorrect;
    }

    /**
     * Set question
     *
     * @param \QuizBundle\Entity\Question $question
     *
     * @return Answer
     */
    public function setQuestion(\QuizBundle\Entity\Question $question = null)
    {
        $this->question = $question;
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Get question
     * @return \QuizBundle\Entity\Question
     */
    public function getQuestion()
    {
        return $this->question;
    }
}
```

Question Entity:

```
/**
 * Question
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="question")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="QuizBundle\Repository\QuestionRepository")
 */
class Question
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Answer", mappedBy="question", cascade={"remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $answers;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->answers = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="image", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $image;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="question", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $question;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set image
     *
     * @param string $image
     *
     * @return Question
     */
    public function setImage($image)
    {
        $this->image = $image;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get image
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getImage()
    {
        return $this->image;
    }

    /**
     * Set question
     *
     * @param string $question
     *
     * @return Question
     */
    public function setQuestion($question)
    {
        $this->question = $question;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get question
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getQuestion()
    {
        return $this->question;
    }

    /**
     * Add answer
     *
     * @param \QuizBundle\Entity\Answer $answer
     *
     * @return Question
     */
    public function addAnswer(\QuizBundle\Entity\Answer $answer)
    {
        $this->answers[] = $answer;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove answer
     *
     * @param \QuizBundle\Entity\Answer $answer
     */
    public function removeAnswer(\QuizBundle\Entity\Answer $answer)
    {
        $this->answers->removeElement($answer);
    }
    /**
     * Get answers
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getAnswers()
    {
        return $this->answers;
    }
}
```

Question Form:

```
class QuestionFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('image');
        $builder->add('question');
        $builder->add('answers', CollectionType::class, array('entry_type' => Answer::class));
    }
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array('data_class' => 'QuizBundle\Entity\Question'));
    }
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'quiz_bundle_question_form_type';
    }
}
```

Answer Form:

```
class AnswerFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('answer');

    }
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array('data_class' => 'QuizBundle\Entity\Answer'));
    }
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'quiz_bundle_answer_form_type';
    }
}
```

Controller Code:

```
public function adminEditRecordAction(){
```

> trying to get a question from DB and the answers

```
        $question = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('QuizBundle:Question')->findOneByIdJoinedToCategory(1);

        $question = new Question();

        $answer = new Answer();
        $answer->setAnswer('answerrr1');
        $answer->setIsCorrect(false);
        $question->getAnswers()->add($answer);
        $form = $this->createForm(QuestionFormType::class, $question);
        return $this->render('QuizBundle:Default:editRecord.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your form class here:

```
$builder->add('answers', CollectionType::class, array('entry_type' => Answer::class));
```

As [Symfony's docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#entry-type) say:

> This is the **field type** for each item in this collection (**e.g. TextType, ChoiceType, etc**). (...)

You've provided entity's classname (`Answer::class`) while it should be some `FormType`'s classname (e.g. `AnswerType:::class`).

Comment: I cannot believe I did it, trying to solve this since yesterday, now I finally get it working. thanks.